# Calling a function inside another function in PL/pgSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, plpgsql

I defined a function to always give me the date of the next Sunday. It works fine, here is the code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION nextSunday() RETURNS date AS $$
DECLARE
    dia_semana INT := CAST(EXTRACT(DOW FROM CURRENT_DATE)as INT);
    dia INT :=  7 - dia_semana;
BEGIN
    RETURN current_date + dia;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

I have another function to dump data into a file and I need to use `nextSunday()` function inside:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION popularTabelaPessoa() RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
COPY(SELECT pe.id, pe.fk_naturalidade, pe.fk_documentacao_pessoal, pe.nome, 
       pe.cpf, pe.data_nascimento, pe.sexo, pe.estado_civil, pe.nome_mae,
       pe.data_alteracao, pe.usuario_banco_alteracao,
       pe.usuario_aplicacao_alteracao
FROM fluxo_lt.banca ba
INNER JOIN corporativo.localidade lo
    ON ba.fk_municipio = lo.id
INNER JOIN fluxo_lt.agendamento_candidato ac
    ON ac.fk_banca = ba.id
INNER JOIN info_detran.processo as pr
    ON ac.fk_processo = pr.id
INNER JOIN info_detran.candidato as ca
    ON pr.fk_candidato = ca.id
INNER JOIN corporativo.pessoa as pe
    ON ca.fk_pessoa = pe.id
WHERE ba.data = (SELECT nextSunday())
ORDER BY lo.nome, pe.nome)

TO '/tmp/dump.sql';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

But it is not working. The field `ba.data` is `date`, the same type as return value of `nextSunday()` function. The code is executed without any errors, but the file is blank. If I hardcode a date it works just fine. Already tried everything (casting, putting it into a variable, pass as a argument to the function) but nothing worked so far.

I'm using Postgres 9.3.

Comment: Are you sure that date returned from function is the same as date you hardcoded? Also, I so not see `nextsunday` function in the second piece of code, where it should be used?

Comment: @TomasGreif Yes, the function is returning a date type. You can test that and see for yourself. I edited the question and now is showing the nextSunday() function, sorry about that.

Comment: I don't mean type, but value (2014-02-16). What will happen when you try `(date_trunc('week', current_date) + interval '1 week' - interval '1 day')::date` instead of `(select nextsunday())`? Btw. I think you do not need to wrap `nextSunday()` in select - `ba.data = nextsunday()` should also work - for example try `select 1 where nextsunday() > current_date`. It would be good if you add working solution with hard-coded date.

Comment: Please put your create statement of you `ba` table.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, your function can be much simpler with [**`date_trunc()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION next_sunday()
  RETURNS date
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT date_trunc('week', LOCALTIMESTAMP)::date + 6;
$func$
```

`PARALLEL SAFE` only for Postgres 9.6 or later.

If you have to consider time zones, see:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

If "today" is a Sunday, the above returns it as "next Sunday".
To skip ahead one week in this case:

```
CREATE FUNCTION next_sunday()
  RETURNS date
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT date_trunc('week', LOCALTIMESTAMP + interval '1 day')::date + 6;
$func$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=30ea36dc2493cacc6aaad0692fdf0c29)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d1040/1)</sub>

Or just use `date_trunc('week', LOCALTIMESTAMP)::date + 6` directly, instead of the function.

Next, simplify the call:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION popular_tabela_pessoa()
  RETURNS VOID
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   COPY (
      SELECT pe.id, pe.fk_naturalidade, pe.fk_documentacao_pessoal, pe.nome
           , pe.cpf, pe.data_nascimento, pe.sexo, pe.estado_civil, pe.nome_mae
           , pe.data_alteracao, pe.usuario_banco_alteracao
           , pe.usuario_aplicacao_alteracao
      FROM   fluxo_lt.banca                 ba
      JOIN   corporativo.localidade         lo ON ba.fk_municipio = lo.id
      JOIN   fluxo_lt.agendamento_candidato ac ON ac.fk_banca = ba.id
      JOIN   info_detran.processo           pr ON ac.fk_processo = pr.id
      JOIN   info_detran.candidato          ca ON pr.fk_candidato = ca.id
      JOIN   corporativo.pessoa             pe ON ca.fk_pessoa = pe.id
      WHERE  ba.data = next_sunday()                                 -- NOT: (SELECT next_sunday())
   -- WHERE  ba.data = date_trunc('week', LOCALTIMESTAMP)::date + 6  -- direct alternative
      ORDER  BY lo.nome, pe.nome)
   TO '/tmp/dump.sql';
END
$func$;
```

However, this *cannot* explain why your `COPY` fails. Have you made sure the query returns any rows? And have you tried a manual `COPY` without the function wrapper?

You need the [necessary privileges for `COPY TO`](http://id-1.9.3.55.8)
[`\copy` in psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY) may be an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was calling directly function fun1 from another function like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
fun2() returns trigger 
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE AS
$BODY$

BEGIN
raise notice 'trigger fun2 with id: %', new.id;

    fun1(new.id);

    return trigger;

END;

$BODY$;
```

Resolved issue by calling function be with select statement like:

> perform fun1(new.id);

Answer (score 0):

you may call like below

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "eodb_obps"."fee_calculate_obps_form_engine"("request_guid_code" varchar)
  RETURNS table(fee_calculation_obps text) AS $BODY$

 DECLARE
 json_data  record;
 query varchar; 
BEGIN
    
select eodb_obps_data_json from eodb_obps.eodb_obps_certificate_request_info where eodb_obps_certificate_info_guid = ( select request_ref_identifier
from process.request  where request_guid= request_guid_code )::text into json_data;

query = 'SELECT * from eodb_obps.fee_calculate_obps(  '''||json_data.eodb_obps_data_json::text||''' , ''JSON'')';

raise notice '%',query; 
    
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE query;

end ;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
    
select "eodb_obps"."fee_calculate_obps_form_engine"('d970e702-77c9-4bf7-b43a-cf47ecc64c5e');
```